# Spark Failing to Parse MySQL Text Column

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

Spark is  failing to correctly parse a TEXT column from a MySQL database. The TEXT field contains long entries which include newline characters and quotation marks.

I was initially having problems reading in a file from a `.csv` format (same thing, Spark not correctly parsing multiline entries despite trying various options for the `libParser`), so I uploaded it to MySQL in order to have a cleaner read into Spark.

As you can see in the error below, a character sequence in the long TEXT column is likely causing Spark to inadvertently split the entry up among multiple columns, which is leading to text being placed in a field of type `java.sql.TimeStamp`.

Any suggetions on how to avoid this issue?

### MySQL Read

```
val notesDF = spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", jdbcUrl)
    .option("driver", jdbcDriver)
    .option("dbtable", "noteevents")
    .option("user", "root")
    .option("password", "password")
    .load()
```

### ERROR

```
17/04/13 00:53:34 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, lol-w-0.c.sunlit-aura-164219.internal): 

java.sql.SQLException: Value '17422532167853
    2151-08-040000-00-00 00:00:000000-00-00 00:00:00Discharge summaryReport00∩┐╜yAdmission Date:  [**2151-7-16**]       Discharge Date:  [**2151-8-4**]


Service:
ADDENDUM:

RADIOLOGIC STUDIES:  Radiologic studies also included a chest
CT, which confirmed cavitary lesions in the left lung apex
consistent with infectious process/tuberculosis.  This also
moderate-sized left pleural effusion.

HEAD CT:  Head CT showed no intracranial hemorrhage or mass
effect, but old infarction consistent with past medical
history.

ABDOMINAL CT:  Abdominal CT showed lesions of
T10 and sacrum most likely secondary to osteoporosis. These can
be followed by repeat imaging as an outpatient.



                            [**First Name8 (NamePattern2) **] [**First Name4 (NamePattern1) 1775**] [**Last Name (NamePattern1) **], M.D.  [**MD Number(1) 1776**]

Dictated By:[**Hospital 1807**]
MEDQUIST36

D:  [**2151-8-5**]  12:11
T:  [**2151-8-5**]  12:21
JOB#:  [**Job Number 1808**]
                                   ' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp
```

Comment: Have you tried with specifying delimiters using `.options(delimiter=",")`

Comment: @Pushkr are you referring to setting this option when doing the read from the .csv? In that case, yes. Sadly it still didn't work.

Comment: Yes , I was referring option while doing spark.read. But what version of spark you are using? csv is now supported in spark2.x version. If you are using earlier version, databricks has csv package that you can use. See more information @ https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: I'm using 2.0.2. Originally, I was using the supported csv read, but it was mixing up the columns. I thought uploading the file to a database and then reading it in would resolve the issue, but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Looks like you need to perform some data cleansing operation before feeding it to `read.csv`. Hypothetically, if you know where your text data begins and ends, you can replace all offending characters like commas or newlines with something unique not found in data and then run `read.csv` that way coulmns will be identified correctly. You can re-replace commas later in your process.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Pushkar pointed out, the way to fix the issue was to preprocess the data. Just in case someone else has as similar problem handling large text fields in a `.csv` for Spark, here's what I did:

1. Load `.csv` into MySQL.
2. Remove any newline characters/non-ascii characters.
   `update tablename set columnname = REPLACE(CONVERT(columnname USING ascii), '?', '');`
3. Export the table (include column names) to a `.csv` and use the properly formatted file.